# How do I Send mail on Updating user active in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have changed the registration process a bit as shown below. When from the admin panel when superuser checks active, the registered user() should get mail on pressing save button. How can I do that?

Views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "User saved")
            return redirect("accounts:login")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error in form")
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', context)
```

I achieved it through this link: [Send an email if to a Django User if their active status is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451275/send-an-email-if-to-a-django-user-if-their-active-status-is-changed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending emails when a user is activated in the Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441725/sending-emails-when-a-user-is-activated-in-the-django-admin)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451275/send-an-email-if-to-a-django-user-if-their-active-status-is-changed

Comment: Use [django signals api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch), this will work.